# Prince of persia game linux wine error

Tags: wine, games

I tried installing Prince of Persia using lutris on my Debian. It opens up but then it flashes and closes. I also tried running it with the wine installer. It showed me two errors. The first was:

> An error has occured while analyzing your hardware configuration (result not found :directx/num3dadapters).Do you want to launch the game anyway?

When I hit "yes", I get another error saying:

> Unable to find POPData.BF please see readme.txt file for technical support.

I do have a file called `POPData.BF` in the directory of the game. Is there a fix for this?

I used a GOG of the game and wine 5.0.3.

Comment: There are currently [four issues](https://www.gog.com/games?query=prince persia) of the game available on GOG. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Prince of persia sands of time

Comment: Not all Windows programs work with`wine`. Check with https://winehq.org

Comment: Yes its there on wine . It even kind of runs a bit but then it crashes.

Comment: Ok i have currently fixed the first error. Is there a solution to the other error?

Comment: Use proton by adding non steam game in steam https://www.protondb.com/app/13600 Also see https://linux-gaming.kwindu.eu/index.php?title=Main_Page